# (13) Permission denied: httpd: could not open error log file Unable to open logs

Tags: apache, centos, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I'm trying to setup Apache (httpd) with mod_wsgi to run a single Django site.

```
(13)Permission denied: httpd: could not open error log file /var/mail/django-error-log.
Unable to open logs
```

I've already done: `chown apache django-error-log` to make sure the ownership is set to apache and verified it with `ls -l`

```
ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r--. 1 apache root 0 Jan 10 01:40 django-error-log
```

Any idea what's causing the permission denied?

Comment: Added it to the question @Himal

Comment: You have the wrong user group. try `chown apache:apache django-error-log` also you might have to add write permission to the apache group with, `chmod g+w django-error-log`

Comment: As a note, i think this is off-topic for SO.you should post these types of questions in serverfault

Comment: For the record, I am having a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

Highly possible you have SELinux Enforcing.

Just disable it (SELINUX=disabled) and try again.

1.) vi /etc/selinux/config

```
# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#     enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#     permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#     disabled - No SELinux policy is loaded.
SELINUX=disabled
# SELINUXTYPE= can take one of these two values:
#     targeted - Targeted processes are protected,
#     minimum - Modification of targeted policy. Only selected processes are protected.
#     mls - Multi Level Security protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
```

2.) And then "**reboot**"

3.-) Try again

You can use "**getenforce**" command to verify the current status, as follows:

```
[root@instance-1 selinux]# getenforce
Disabled
[root@instance-1 selinux]#
```

Regards